# C programming Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c, arrays

The following code is from a practice test. The question is to determine if it is correct or not and what it would print if it is. It does compile and print but I do not understand why it is printing what it is.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *getThreeNumbers()
{
    int i; int a[3]; int *p;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", a+i);
    }
    p=a;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int *q; int i;
    q=getThreeNumbers();
    printf("the number you entered are:\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n", q[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not everything that compiles is good C code. What you are doing here is extremely dangerous.

You are declaring an array on the stack in `getThreeNumber();` and returning a pointer to it to the callee (`main` in this case). `int a[3]` gets destroyed when `getThreeNumber()` finishes execution, so the pointer that is passed back to `main` could contain garbage.

This provokes *undefined behaviour*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *getThreeNumbers()
{
    int i;
    int a[3];  // a is created on the stack, it is only valid within
               //the scope of this function
    int *p;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", a+i);
    }
    p=a;

    return p;   //a will die at this point and there is no guarantee
                //that other values including garbage is not put in its place,
               // but you are returning its address anyway. BAD IDEA
}
```

A correct way to do it would be to allocate the memory on the heap:

```
int *getThreeNumbers()
{
    int i;
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    }
    return p;
}
```

remember though that you have to free the memory in your main:

```
int main()
{
    int *q; int i;
    q=getThreeNumbers();
    printf("the number you entered are:\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n", q[i]);

    free(q);  //not necessary in this case, but good form
    return 0;
}
```

However the exact opposite of what you are trying to do is allowed (and common in C programming). You can send the address of your stack allocated array to a function that alters it. This is done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void changeNumbers( int * p)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int q[3]; int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i) q[i]=0; //initialize to 0


    printf("the values before changing:\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n", q[i]);
    printf("\n\n\n", q[i]);

    changeNumbers(q);

    printf("the array after modification:\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n", q[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason the second program behaves well, is because the array is never destroyed until it goes out of scope. `changeNumbers()`'s stack frame goes on "top" of main, which means the memory addresses below it are safe from going out of scope and being destroyed.

In simple words: 
In the first situation when `main` is accessing the values in array, its owner function is already done executing and it's stack has resolved.(every variable `getThreeNumbers()` declared on the stack could be garbage)

In the second situation. when `changeNumbers()` is accessing the array, the owner of the array (`main`) is not done executing yet! it is still chilling and waiting for  `changeNumbers()` to finish execution before taking control again.

Comment: "The correct way" should perhaps be "*A* correct way" .. there are other options which are arguably better, e.g. having the caller create an array of 3 ints and pass that as parameter.

Comment: @M.M initially I was alluding to the most directly similar approach that would take care of his issue. Funny that I was providing him the other idiom just before you commented